# Usage of dispatch events in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

which one is better to share data Behavior Subject or dispatch event (document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(--))) in angular7 application

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to that. But the "Angular way" would be the `BehaviourSubject`. Custom Events through `document.dispatch()` are strongly discouraged in Angular.